# problem in visualizing dashboard in python

Tags: python, plotly-dash, dashboard

I'm running a short dashboard example in Python using dash library. I'm using Jupyter notebook. The first thing is to create a file named app.py and running this line in conda terminal
`python app.py`
and the following code in Jupyter. When it's finished I should go to the browser and visit  the http address but all I get is the "unable to reach the site" error. What could go wrong?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Run this app with `python app.py` and
# visit http://127.0.0.1:8050/ in your web browser.

import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

# assume you have a "long-form" data frame
# see https://plotly.com/python/px-arguments/ for more options
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Fruit": ["Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas", "Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas"],
    "Amount": [4, 1, 2, 2, 4, 5],
    "City": ["SF", "SF", "SF", "Montreal", "Montreal", "Montreal"]
})

fig = px.bar(df, x="Fruit", y="Amount", color="City", barmode="group")

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),

    html.Div(children='''
        Dash: A web application framework for Python.
    '''),

    dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph',
        figure=fig
    )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: Try a different port

Comment: To expand on Chris's comment, you can write `app.run_server(debug=True, port=8051)` if you want to run on port 8051, for example.